# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambigous when trying to index an array

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to put all elements of rbs into a new array if the elements in var(another numpy array) is >=0 and <=.1 . However when I try the following code I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

```
rbs = [ish[4] for ish in realbooks]
for book in realbooks:
    var -= float(str(book[0]).replace(":", ""))
    bidsred = rbs[(var <= .1) and (var >=0)]
```

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which line causes the error? Also please format your code so it actually runs.

Comment: It would help if you printed out the value of var. At a guess, the problem is in the string/float/text replaced variable you're decrementing... What does the original data look like that would require that series of operations?

Comment: Aside from being a clear duplicate (the problem is caused by the `and` on the last line in the example, which is exactly the setup in the canonical), the title given here was misleading - the problem **did not** occur "when trying to index an array", but instead when trying to combine two masks with `and`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `and` keyword is used by Python to test between two booleans. How can an array be a boolean? If 75% of its items are `True`, is it `True` or `False`? Therefore, numpy refuses to compare the two.

Therefore, use either `c[a & b]` or `c[np.logical_and(a, b)]`. Either approach to combining the `a` and `b` arrays - `a & b` or `np.logical_and(a, b)` - will produce a boolean array with the same size as the input arrays `a` and `b`, which is necessary if the next step is to index into a same-sized array `c`.

A `list` of boolean values cannot be used for indexing instead. NumPy will interpret that as a list of index values (treating `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`), so the output would contain multiple copies of the first two elements of the array, rather than a masked version.

Similarly, to choose elements from `c` where *either* of the corresponding elements from `a` or `b` is true, use `c[a | b]` or `c[np.logical_or(a,b)]`.

Answer (score 13):

This error message normally results from trying to use Python boolean operators (`not`, `and`, `or`) or comparison expressions involving Numpy arrays, e.g.:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-5, 5)
>>> (x > -2) and (x < 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-475a0a26e11c>", line 1, in <module>
    (x > -2) and (x < 2)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

That's because such comparisons, unlike comparisons between built-in Python types, create arrays of booleans rather than single booleans:

```
>>> x > -2
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> x < 2
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

To fix this, replace the `and` operator with a call to `np.logical_and`, which broadcasts the AND operation over two arrays of `np.bool`.

```
>>> np.logical_and(x > -2, x < 2)
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> x[np.logical_and(x > -2, x < 2)]
array([-1,  0,  1])
```

However, such arrays of booleans cannot be used to index into ordinary Python lists, so the result of the list comprehension must be converted to an array first:

```
rbs = np.array([ish[4] for ish in realbooks])
```