# python the-truth-value-of-an-array.. ambigious error

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, vector

I'm trying to multiply 2 vectors using numpy and compare them, for some reasong it gives me error.. the data is from a CSV file
I have found

[The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambigous when trying to index an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647471/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambigous-when-trying-t)

and more case of this type, but it is really different from my case..
my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],  delimiter = ',')
X = data[:, 1:]
Y = data[:, 0]
   #argv[1] is mnist_train_1vs7vs8.csv
wMatrix=(3,len(X[0]))
np.zeros(wMatrix)
for i in range(0,len(Y)):
        maxWx=0
        for wIndex in range (0,1):
            if ( np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex] ,X[i]) < np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex+1],X[i]) ):
                maxWx=wIndex+1
```

it gives me error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is   
ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

I'm just trying to multiply a vector with a vector of the same size, and i don't understand why it won't let me..
HELP..?

Comment: The error isn't being caused by the multiplication, but by the comparison. Have you tried *printing out* the values you're comparing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do as @kindall suggested and print out the value of `np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex] ,X[i]) < np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex+1],X[i])` you'd see it's an array of booleans.

You should probably do something like:

```
res = np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex] ,X[i]) < np.dot(wMatrix[wIndex+1],X[i])
if res.all():
   ...
```

This depends on when you actually mean in `<` :)

Comment: Wow, the solution is exactly what the error message says! :-)