# When I used Onehotencoder getting the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

When I used `Onehotencoder` error in python 3.7 the following error is showed up. Please give a solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=X[3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)
```

I am getting an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-a28c69982fc5>", line 15, in <module>
    X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).values.reshape(-1,1)

  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 372, in fit_transform
    return super().fit_transform(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 571, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 347, in fit
    self._fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)

  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 76, in _fit
    if self.categories != 'auto':

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: If you set your X variable like this `X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values`, then I believe the categories would be gone.  As in, no column headings. X[3] will then return the first three rows of your array.  Can you share what some of your data looks like?

Comment: @MarkMoretto the documentation does specify that `categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column`

Comment: If you could provide more info, that would be great.  Check this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253975/sklearn-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous-use